# HTML5 video "ended" event sometimes not firing when video ends

Tags: angular, html5-video, electron

In an app that me and my team are developing, we're utilizing HTML5 video component to display `.mp4` videos in full screen. The app is ASP.NET Web API on backend with SignalR, and it's Electron app with Angular 4 on frontend. It works in the following way:

- Once the Electron app is started, it pings the API
- Backend serves a url to the app to play via SignalR
- App then loads the video and notifies backend that the video has been loaded and started
- Once `(ended)` is triggered, we notify backend that the video has ended
- The app then displays some other content for a configurable amount of time (served by backend)
- Once the timeout expires on backend we notify Electron app to display the next video to be played
- Clicking on the currently displayed video will interrupt it and other content will be displayed. Once the timeout expires, backend serves the interrupted video
- Repeat

One of the issues that we've discovered recently is that *sometimes* `(ended)` is not triggered when the video ends and our app stays stuck because it never produced a callback to backend that the video has ended.

Here's the code:

**Component for video display**

```
<div (click)="clickOnScreen()" class="full-size" [@fadeInOut]>
    <video muted autoplay preload="auto" (ended)="onVideoEnded()" #videoplayer>
        <source [src]="sanitizeUrl(videoPath)" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</div>

onVideoEnded() {
        this.logger.info("Video ended.");
        const videoEnded = new VideoEnded();

        const subscription = this.videoPlayerService.videoEnded(videoEnded).subscribe(
            (success) => {
                this.logger.info("Successfully notified Backend that the video has ended.");
                subscription.unsubscribe();
            },
            (error) => {
                this.logger.error(error);
                subscription.unsubscribe();
            });
    }
```

**Loading video once received from backend:**

```
private loadVideo(videos: Videos[]) {
        this.videos = videos;

        if (this.videos === null || this.videos.length === 0) {
            this.logger.warn("no videos sent!");
            return;
        }

        this.logger.info("Starting playback...");
        this.startPlayback();

        this.logger.info("Playback started! Notifying Backend that the video has been displayed...");    
        const subscription = this.videoPlayerService.videoDisplayedOnScreen().subscribe(
            (success) => {
                this.logger.info("Successfully notified Backend that the video has been displayed!");
                subscription.unsubscribe();
            },
            (error) => {
                this.logger.error(error);
                subscription.unsubscribe();
            });
    }

private startPlayback() {
        this.videoNumber = this.videos[0].orderNumber;
        this.videoPath = this.videos[0].videoPath;

        this.videoplayer.nativeElement.currentTime = this.videos[0].currentTime;
        this.videoplayer.nativeElement.load();
        this.cd.markForCheck(); 
    }

clickOnVideo() {        
    const subscription = this.touchService.clickOnVideo().subscribe(
        (success) => {
            subscription.unsubscribe();
        },
        (error) => {
            this.logger.error(error);
            subscription.unsubscribe();
        });
}
```

I've looked if there might be something related to the video itself, however all configured videos can play for like 4-5 hours and then just suddenly stop and `(ended)` is not fired. It there some other way to troubleshoot this? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: HTML Video exposes onended event. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_event_ended

Comment: have you tried tracking the error event as well, in case something else is getting in the way?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal yes, did that yesterday and let it run during the night. Still nothing. I see in the logs that it just stops at a certain moment and that's it - I have to manually trigger it by clicking on the screen. However, one interesting thing that I noticed this morning is this:

`ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(9636)] [.DisplayCompositor-0E0AA130]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.`

I'll investigate further, however it's still not very clear what is happening.